# Pandas groupby rolling mean, but only for the most recent row to save calculation time

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe that is very large, in this format:

```
id     time     price
ABC    01:04     100
XYZ    01:04      50
QRS    01:04      25
ABC    01:03     100
XYZ    01:03      50
QRS    01:03      25
ABC    01:02     100
XYZ    01:02      50
QRS    01:02      25
ABC    01:01     100
XYZ    01:01      50
QRS    01:01      25
ABC    01:00     100
XYZ    01:00      50
QRS    01:00      25
```

In this case, 1:04pm is the most recent data, and I want a rolling mean of price for each ticker, going back 4 periods. I don't care about the rolling mean starting at 1:03pm or 1:02pm or 1:01pm.

I have this code so far which takes care of everything except it calculates means for all time periods, not just the most recent one:

```
rmean = db.groupby('id').rolling(window=3).mean()
```

The reason I need to only calculate it for the first time period is because my actual data is massive and it takes too long.

Expected output:

```
id     time     price
ABC    01:04     100
XYZ    01:04      50
QRS    01:04      25
```

Comment: Add a sample output.

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh done, but you also need to know that I want to avoid calculating all possible rolling means...

Comment: In output, price column is rolling mean? It doesn't seem `mean` to me.

Comment: ya, its a groupby and a mean... ABC is always 100 so the mean is 100...

Comment: You can just filter dataframe where `id == 'ABC'` and then compute rolling mean.

Comment: don't think that results in the desired output.

Comment: Yes. I got confused a bit. So you want one rolling mean for each id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.groupby.agg`, to compute the rolling mean for only the recent data you can take `head(3)` and compute mean of it.

Use:

```
new_df = (df.sort_values(by=['time'], ascending = False)
            .groupby('id', as_index = False)
            .agg(
              time = ('time', 'first'), 
              price = ('price', lambda x: x.head(3).values.mean())
             ))
```

Prints:

```
>>> new_df
    id   time  price
0  ABC  01:04    100
1  QRS  01:04     25
2  XYZ  01:04     50
```

Comment: While this solution works, I don't think hardcoding .head(3) in there is very good practice. Maybe try abstracting it into a variable coupled with a .loc?

Comment: 3 here is the window size, and that is supposed to be hardcoded or the OP can assign it to a variable and place it there.

Comment: It works, and its quick, but I don't really understand why it works...

Comment: @helloimgeorgia You only wanted to take `rolling mean` with window size 3 for recent data in each `group`, which simplifies to `mean` of first 3 rows in each `group`.

Comment: using `sort_values` before `head` in agg function could could give you a more "fail proof" way of selecting top 3

Comment: @Ukrainian-serge Yes. Looked like the df was sorted. May be I should sort the df before the groupby.

Comment: it depends what you want. maybe do it before AND after to be safe? not sure on the specifics of `agg` in sorting. i just find myself taking the safe route and having all the bases covered

Comment: Order is maintained in groupby and agg. So sorting once is safe.